# How to change the port number for hpi:run

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins

I'm trying to run the below command to package the hpi file in target folder

```
 hpi:run
```

And observed the below error message that says the port has been used already. I just tried to kill the port by manually but i don't have privilege to do that.  Is it possible to customize the port no by passing as an argument -Dhpi.port=xxx something like this?

Exception:

> java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind  at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)     at
>   sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
>     at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:321)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:236)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.MavenServerConnector.doStart(MavenServerConnector.java:120)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:366)     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer.doStart(JettyServer.java:73)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.maven.plugins.hpi.AbstractJettyMojo.startJetty(AbstractJettyMojo.java:567)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.maven.plugins.hpi.RunMojo.startJetty(RunMojo.java:660)
>     at
>   org.jenkinsci.maven.plugins.hpi.AbstractJettyMojo.execute(AbstractJettyMojo.java:390)
>     at org.jenkinsci.maven.plugins.hpi.RunMojo.execute(RunMojo.java:353)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>   2019-02-06 13:34:37.404:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:main: FAILED
>   org.eclipse.jetty.maven.plugin.JettyServer@4802791f:
>   java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Jenkins](https://jenkinsci.github.io/maven-hpi-plugin/run-mojo.html) documentation:

> Runs Jenkins with the current plugin project.
>   This only needs the source files to be compiled, so run in the compile
>   phase.
>   To specify the HTTP port, use -Djetty.port=PORT

So, try to use `-Djetty.port=PORT` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

`-Djetty.port=PORT` no longer works. Use `mvn hpi:run -Dport=PORT`

See https://www.jenkins.io/doc/developer/tutorial/run/